# AWS S3 file restore - deleted file(Delete Marker)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Using AWS SDK Created S3 versioning, Its working fine. And Each file creating unique version id. Using getObject method i can retrieve version id. The same scenario i deleted file, in versioning "Delete Marker" added.

1. How do i get deleted file version id?
2. How do i restore this file using AWS SDK?

Comment: Have you read this ? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/restoring-objects-java.html

Comment: Have you examined the response to listObjectVersions?  What language of SDK?   If you do getObject against a deleted file, you should get the versionId of the delete marker, which you can then use to deleteObject... deleting the delete marker is how an object is restored, but it's hard to say more without the specific language mentioned.

Comment: Hi Michael am using PHP SDK.

Comment: Delete Marker added to deleted file, am using getObject method to get version id, But its returning with null.

Comment: Using listObjectVersions can get all objects, is there any better option get delete marker file version Id. S3 bucket will gradually increase in GB's, for one file  i have to search whole bucket. Any comments?